# Python store password more securely via POST API request

Tags: python, api, security, passwords, python-requests

I have a script that utilizes the request module to create a POST request.

The password is stored in plain text in the script.

I am concerned that this is blatantly insecure, but I am not sure how to make it more secure.

Any suggestions on steps I can take to avoid storing the password in plain text in the script to make the request?

```
#Set request parameters
url = 'https://apiexample.com/test'
#ISSUE: password is plain text
user = 'api_example'
pwd = 'plaintextnopes'

#Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

#Build HTTP Request
response = requests.post(url=url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers ,data=j)

#Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Response Text', response.text, 'Error Response:',response.json())
        exit()
```

EDIT:
The account is the system user that has access to write records to the database, this is static, it will not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this script runs interactively, you could ask the user to type the password on the keyboard by calling `input()` or `raw_input()` (depending on what version of Python you're using).

You could store the password in a separate file, which isn't totally secure but does let you share the script without sharing the password.

You could get the base64 encoded value of the username+password and include that in the headers directly, instead of passing them via the `auth=` parameter.  However this only protects the password from a casual snooper; it's easy to reconstruct the username and password from the encoded value.

Comment: The account is the system user that has access to write records to the database, this is static, it will not change. I think I would like to at least store it in a separate file, and a base64 encoded value included in the header might at least be a bit more secure. What would the syntax look like in order to pass in the base64 encoded value in the header instead of the auth param? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: `headers = {..., 'Basic: %s' % b64encode('%s:%s' % (user, pwd))}`